# ReferenceError: babelHelpers is not defined ./node_modules/react-avatar-editor/dist/index.js/</i< node_modules/react-avatar-editor/dist/index.js:1

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, babel-loader

I'm getting an ReferenceError: babelHelpers is not defined, while importing react-avatar-editor,
**PLEASE HELP!**

Comment: Is it possible to share what you have done so that its possible to see what could be wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

looks like version 11.0.9 onward has this issue.
You may want to use version 11.0.7.

in your package-lock.json find "react-avatar-editor" and replace the version number with "11.0.7".

[edit]
Mentioned here:
https://github.com/mosch/react-avatar-editor/issues/340